# Is it possible to log the request execution time for spring cloud gateway service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I have few spring cloud gateway service routing requests to few services. Is it possible to capture the request execution time using some configuration?

If not what are the possible ways to capture the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AOP. In Spring I use 2 dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Define pointcuts and use `@Around` annotation. Method have argument: `org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint`. Don't forget return response:

```
private Object proceedSoapExecution(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    long startExcecution=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object response = joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs());
    long endExcutution=System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeDuration=endExcutution-startExcecution;
    logTimeExcecution(soapTimeDuration, timeDuration);
    return response;
}
```